# Solution for : QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, yolov4

So, I am a complete beginner in Python. This is my first ever application in this. I have these several files of Python classes. Using PyQT5 to make a desktop GUI object tracking app. When I am calling them from one another this error shows up.

> QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

main.py

```
def main():
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 #window = QMainWindow()
 # Convert darknet weights to tensorflow model
 cmd1 = "python save_model.py --model yolov4" 
 # Run yolov4 deep sort object tracker on video


 cmd2 = "python object_tracker.py --video ./data/video/project_video_2.mp4 --output 
 ./outputs/output.avi --model yolov4 --dont_show --count"

 TrackerProcess.sendParams(cmd1, cmd2, app)
 window = TrackerProcess.main()



 app.exec_()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

trackerProcess.py

```
def sendParams(cmd1, cmd2, a):
 global command1, command2, app
 command1 = cmd1
 command2 = cmd2
 app = a

def start_process_three(self):
 #self.stop()        
 main_design.sendFile("./outputs/output.avi", app)
 main_design.main()

def main():
 #app = QApplication(sys.argv)

 w = MainWindow()
 w.show()
 #app.exec()
 return w
 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

main_design.py

```
def sendFile(passedFileName, a):
 global fileName, app
 fileName = passedFileName
 app = a


def main():
 #app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 #global app
 Frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
 player = VideoPlayer()
 player.resize(1024, 864)
 ui = Ui_Frame()
 ui.setupUi(Frame, player)
 player.show()
 Frame.show()
 player.playVideoFile(fileName, app)
 app.exec_()

#return player

    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

VideoPlayer.py

```
 def playVideoFile(self, fileName, a):
   #fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
            #QDir.homePath())
    global app
    app = a
    if fileName != '':
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName))) 
    if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()
    else:
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
def main():
 app.exec_()
 return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Please someone give a proper solution. I am tired of searching for a loophole in the code. Any advice is invited. Thank you.

Comment: Only the script that you're actually running will go through the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. I'd suggest you to avoid splitting your script in too many files unless you *really* know what you're doing and why. Start by making your program in a single script and make it work, first. *Then*, and *if it makes sense*, refactor your code in order to use multiple files, and use the `if __main__` block in the actual main script, which is the one that will actually create and run the **only** QApplication instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I refactored my code and made them appear in fewer files. Tried to call app.exec_() in one main file only. Finally the error is gone!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling app.exec_() multiple times. If you only call it once in main.py, there should be no error.

```py
# main.py
import sys

def createTestButton(window):
  button = QPushButton("Test", window)
  return button

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication()
  mainWindow = QMainWindow(x, y, w, h) # x, y, w, and h are the dimensions for the window
  button = createTestButton(mainWindow)
  button.setGeometry(100, 100, 50, 20) # Change the dimensions of the button
  button.show()

  sys.exit(app.exec_()) # This line makes it so that the program ends once app's mainloop is done
```

Comment: But, say, I if dont call it in the other classes, will the gui objects of those classes work? For example, I have tried not calling app_exec() under VideoPlayer, but found the buttons not working. Was that for app_exec() or some other reason? So, what is the workaround? Sorry, if I am sounding silly. :(

Comment: The only reason I can think of that would cause those widgets to not appear is that you aren't giving them a parent. Normally people create a QApplication and a QMainWindow. Whenever you create a new widget like a button, pass the QMainWindow object into that widget's constructor.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include a simple example of how to start an application and create things like buttons.